# EDAC memory error after upgrade server SuperMicro with CentOS 7. Is these specific errors of motherboard, OS or broken RAM module?

Tags: linux, memory, centos7, supermicro

I have server on [SuperMicro MBD-X9DRD-EF](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9drd-ef.cfm) motherboard. It worked well at CentOS7 during the year with one CPU (Intel Original Xeon X6 E5-2620v2) and 128 Gb (8x16 Gb) LVDDR (1600MHz Crucial ECC Reg RTL (PC3-12800)) memory. Last month we upgrade this server by adding second CPU and additional 128 Gb memory, absolutely identical to the existing ones. 
But after intensively usage the server (during 3-4 days), we start to receive (very frequently) such errors:

```
[root@GBserver log]# dmesg
[614781.869098] EDAC sbridge MC1: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
[614781.869104] EDAC sbridge MC1: CPU 6: Machine Check Event: 0 Bank 7: 8c00004000010090
[614781.869106] EDAC sbridge MC1: TSC 0
[614781.869108] EDAC sbridge MC1: ADDR 38126a6c40
[614781.869110] EDAC sbridge MC1: MISC 14066ca86
[614781.869112] EDAC sbridge MC1: PROCESSOR 0:306e4 TIME 1473082855 SOCKET 1 APIC 20
[614782.595676] EDAC MC1: 1 CE memory read error on CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0 (channel:0 slot:0 page:0x38126a6 offset:0xc40 grain:32 syndrome:0x0 -  area:DRAM err_code:0001:0090 socket:1 ha:0 channel_mask:1 rank:1)
```

And the output of edac-util:

```
[root@GBserver log]# edac-util -v
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#3_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#1_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#2_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#0_Ha#0_Chan#3_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc1: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc1: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0: 296182 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#1_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#2_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#3_DIMM#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#1_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#2_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
mc1: csrow1: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#3_DIMM#1: 0 Corrected Errors
```

> **mc1: csrow0: CPU_SrcID#1_Ha#0_Chan#0_DIMM#0: 296182 Corrected Errors**

Is these errors arose via motherboard, CPU or OS fault, or we have broken memory chip? What we should to do? How to find broken memory module?

Answer (score 0):

After 3 weeks there were about 11M corrected errors logged. I found broken memory module after seen the BIOS log. [image]
**This is the answer my question.**
Next, I will remove the broken module and will replace it by another.